# How can I deserialise a String in a Stream in java?

Tags: java, string, serialization, functional-programming, stream

I have a String, for example:
"NEXT":"mode1":2,"mode2":3,"mode3":7

I'd want to seralise it within a stream to extract the "mode1":2, "mode2":3, etc into a HashMap.

How is this possible?

Comment: This has multiple strings right? It's not a one single string? Please show your input?

Comment: That's not a String !

Comment: Is there a fixed format for the String which you want to deserialise?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Your question isn't really about deserializing `Strings` in a `Stream` is it, are you trying to convert a JSON string into a `HashMap`? If so, use Jackson or another library.

Comment: I don't even see a valid json string here. Please go through this and post a minimal and reproducible example first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `"NEXT":` does not belong to your input string you could do the following:

```java
String input = "\"mode1\":2,\"mode2\":3,\"mode3\":7";
Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of(input.split(","))
            .map(it -> it.split(":"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                it -> it[0].replace("\"", ""),
                it -> Integer.parseInt(it[1])));
```